# How can I pass a dynamic parameter-that I will create with some random library- in testNg xml?

Tags: java, testng

I want to pass a dynamic parameter to a test case from testng xml, my parameter is something like:

```
String dynamicParameter=generateRandomStringForMail();
```

Here is my testcase:

```
   @Test()
    public void customerCreatorAllProducts () throws Exception {
            setup();
            Functions.pages.LoginPage login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Functions.pages.LoginPage.class);
            login.navigateRegisterPage().createFixedPasswordCustomerRequiredFields(dynamicParameter);
    }
```

I will be using this parameter in other cases as well, how can i do this from testng.xml or with something else?

Comment: JUnit tests are run independently, so you'd have to either seed the `Random` object used in `generateRandomStringForMail` or do something like make `dynamicParameter` a static variable.  By the way, I would highly recommend using either a seeded Random object or just using a known String; these are much better practice for Unit Tests.

Comment: I am using TestNg, not JUnit.

Comment: Same principle.

Comment: How can i pass this to other tests after parameter is defined- not randomed with each iteration-

Comment: Exactly like I said, by making it a static variable that's a member of the class.  But why even generate a "random" String in the first place?  Your Unit Test results will be much more consistent if you test against a known String every time.

Comment: I am actually not looking for consistency, I want to create a new user each time when I run the test suite, and use this user in other cases as well.

Comment: I see.  Regardless, a static variable is your best bet.

Comment: Though, making it static won't work for me:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219226/discussion-between-alper-oguzkan-and-ajc2000).

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with testing.xml, but Mockito immediately comes to mind for this: http://mockito.org.

1. add Mockito to your project (e.g. through the build.gradle page)
2. add the import to your test file:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

3. within your test class, create a mock of the class which has the generateRandomStringForMail() method.  In my current project, I have

```
DefaultFileService mockFileService = mock(DefaultFileService.class);
```

4. define what you want the method to return under these test conditions, e.g.

```
when(mockFileService.generateRandomFileName()).thenReturn("fileName");
```

5. Whenever your tests need to use the result of the method in question, you can use "fileName", because you have told the test environment to give this response.  My project has a method to update the image file associated with an inventory item, which process includes using the DefaultFileService to generate a random file name, then passing the image file and the new file name to the DefaultFileService to save the file in the system.  My test code can't see or guess what file name would actually be produced, but my 'when' line above has resolved that problem for the purposes of testing my QuiltController class:

```
quiltController.update(data, mockFile);
verify(mockFileService).save(mockFile, "fileName"); // confirms the save() method was called with the expected parameters
```

It feels pretty similar to what you are trying to do, so hopefully that helps you proceed if you do want to explore Mockito.  Don't be surprised if you need to refactor some of your work to make it more testable.  I did, and have better code as a result.  Give it a go :)